# change product images path in magento site

Tags: magento

In Product view page, image is serving from this path : [link](http://test.collagekingapp.com/media/catalog/product/cache/1/image/350x350/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/b/a/baby-ball-large.jpg)

```
/media/catalog/product/cache/1/image/350x350/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/b/a/ball.jpg
```

it's using 350x350 size

but i wanted to serve from this path : [link2](http://test.collagekingapp.com/media/catalog/product/cache/1/image/850x850/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/b/a/baby-ball-large.jpg)

`media/catalog/product/cache/1/image/850x850/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/b/a/ball.jpg`

I need **850x850** size.

we are using : `<?php echo $dexxtz->getImageFeatured($this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'image')); ?>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to tell `Magento` about the resolution for which you want to pick the image, `resize` will help you in your case:-

```
$this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'image')->resize(850, 850);
```

Comment: this did't worked for me as [here](http://test.collagekingapp.com/baby-ball-large.html)

Comment: Have you cleared the cache, as resize should work. Please clear the cache once.

Comment: i tried both cache & browser cache, but it didt worked for me.

Comment: This works fine for me, I tested twice. Can you provide your updated code and also there could be a possibility that your function getImageFeature() is doing some modification with the size.

Comment: we are using this extension : https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/dexxtz-product-zoom.html

Comment: I have not setup the extension, but it seems this extension has provided you the facility to set the height and width of main image in the admin panel. check the first image on the link of extension provided by you.

Comment: if i set more height and width in backend, than in produt view page also it will display more height and width. but i want to change only path

Comment: That will not be possible, magento creates the path according to the size you provide. You need to do custom code for this. Well I am not getting why do you really want to pick the path from cache. You can provide any path and Magento will resize on its own and will then pick the image accordingly.

Comment: our seo team wanted same path in both sitemap and in product view page. also they want bigger size images in both path. so in sitemap image is bigger, but in product view page, image is not bigger in size, so i want same path for both link1 and link2.

Comment: You can do one thing in this case, set 850 in backend nd check if its picking the image from correct path and you can set height and width via css to fix image size afterward.

Comment: you are right, now its coming from path i need. but image is displaying in very large size in view page. how to fix using css.

Comment: Add this to your css:- #etalage .etalage_thumb_image{ height: 350px !important; width:350px !important;}

Comment: sorry for delay , please visit [link](http://test.collagekingapp.com/pampers-active-baby-extra-large-size-diapers-56-count-combo.html)

now if you hover  mouse on image, its displaying zooming on right side of the site. please help me for this.

Comment: Since you have modified the size via CSS, either you have to make changes in your zooming functionality OR there is another way instead of getting the image via Magento function, right a function to generate the cache path and there add height and width in image tag. So that when page will be loaded zoom js can work.

Comment: we are using this [extension](https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/dexxtz-product-zoom.html) , please update the answer with the code as you suggested.

Comment: please tell me what file code you need, so that i will post here.

Comment: please inform me what code you want to check ? so that i can post here.

Comment: Just checked your message, I need to setup module and make changes for it. I will update you once done.

Comment: please check when you are free.

Comment: please check when you are free